# Excel VBA - Loop through column and validate

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I'm trying to formulate VBA code in Excel to loop through column D and check if the word 'Incomplete' is present in a cell. **If 'Incomplete' is present in any cell in column D AND the cell in the same row in column G is blank**, then a message box will pop up.

I initially came up with this:

```
If Range("D12").Value = "Incomplete" And Range("G12").Value = "" Then MsgBox ("Please add a comment in G12")
If Range("D13").Value = "Incomplete" And Range("G12").Value = "" Then MsgBox ("Please add a comment in G13")
If Range("D14").Value = "Incomplete" And Range("G12").Value = "" Then MsgBox ("Please add a comment in G14")
If Range("D15").Value = "Incomplete" And Range("G12").Value = "" Then MsgBox ("Please add a comment in G15")
If Range("D16").Value = "Incomplete" And Range("G12").Value = "" Then MsgBox ("Please add a comment in G16")
If Range("D17").Value = "Incomplete" And Range("G12").Value = "" Then MsgBox ("Please add a comment in G17")

And so on..
```

But this is clearly inefficient so I tried to create an automated process:

```
Public Sub Validate()

Dim i As Long

For i = 4 To Rows.Count

Next i

If Cells(i, 4).Value = "Incomplete" And IsEmpty(Cells(i, 7).Value) Then
    MsgBox ("Please add a comment corresponding to an Incomplete task")

End If

End Sub
```

This throws a run-time error '1004'Application-defined or object-defined error.
I've also realised that this will not check if the cell in the same row is blank.

Any help to resolve this would be much appreciated.

Many thanks

Comment: your logic code needs to be within the for...next loop

Comment: Use `WorksheetFunction.CountIfs` and avoid looping.

Comment: Another thing worth noting is that your code will not stop and wait for input at each `MsgBox`. Instead, it will go down the entire column, spamming MsgBoxes at the user until it finishes the range. This might not be your expected bevarior.

Comment: @BigBen that worked perfectly - thank you!

I used the following:

Public Sub Validate()


BatchCount = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Range("D12:D36"), "Incomplete", Range("G12:G36"), "")
    MsgBox BatchCount
    
    
End Sub

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments you logic code is not in the loop, and you will spam the user with message boxes. I would concatenate the cells into a single message, and fix the logic as below:

```
Sub Validate()

    Dim rng As Range, cell As Range
    Dim message As String

    Set rng = Range("D12:D36") 'set your range here

    For Each cell In rng
        If LCase(cell.Value) = "incomplete" And cell.Offset(0, 3).Value = "" Then
            'concatenate a message rather than spamming
            If message = "" Then
                message = "Please add a comment corresponding to an Incomplete task for cell(s) " & vbCrLf & cell.Offset(0, 3).Address
            Else
                message = message & vbCrLf & cell.Offset(0, 3).Address
            End If
        End If
    Next cell
    
    'show a message if any are invalid
    If message <> "" Then
        MsgBox (message)
    End If


End Sub
```

Comment: You are welcome - you could also easily highlight the cells that need to be updated by adding something like `cell.Offset(0, 3).Interior.ColorIndex = 3`

Comment: Even better - your solution is amazing! Once again thank you so much :)